# Reading byte values from char array

Tags: arrays, c, char, byte

I have a function in which I want to check values of some char array bytes of all inserted values.
Example:

```
int check_byte_value(char char_array) {
  int i=0;
  while((char_array+i)!='\0') {
    if((char_array+i) & 0x80 == 0x00) return 0;
    i++;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

How to make it work? I am reading my chars to the array like this:

```
char char_array[10];
int i=0;
while((char_array[i]=getchar())!=EOF) i++;
char_array[i]='\0';
printf("%d", check_byte_value(char_array));
```

Comment: Define "make it work".  Your function appears to "check values", which is in accordance with your specified requirements.

Comment: Turn on all warnings in your compiler.  Just because you use the word "array" in an identifier doesn't mean it is an array.

Comment: When I call this function, it is stuck in while loop

Comment: Please refer to my second comment.